# DRF and Oauth2: creating resource and authorization servers

Tags: django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, django-oauth-toolkit

I have developed a blog like project on the django rest framework and oauth2. I am now trying to separate the resource and authentication servers as shown here: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resource_server.html

I have taken the following steps:

1. set up the auth server as described in the docs
2. added the below to settings.py in the auth server

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'SCOPES': {'users': 'user details', 'read': 'Read scope', 'write': 'Write scope', 'groups': 'Access to your groups', 'introspection': 'introspection'},
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 86400,  # 1 Day.
}
```

3. set up the resource server as described in the docs
4. added this to settings.py in the resource server:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
'RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_URL': 'http://localhost/o/introspect/',
'RESOURCE_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN': 'abc',
}
```

I created the `RESOURCE_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN based` on instructions here: [Django OAuth- Separate Resource and Authorization Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587486/django-oauth-separate-resource-and-authorization-server)

To summarise, I created a superuser for the resource server then added an application to the resource server using the admin site, choosing `confidential` for `client type` and `authorization code` for `authorization grant type`. 'abc' was the random string I chose for the access token.

Nevertheless, I am still facing the following error:

```
Introspection: Failed to get a valid response from the authentication server. Status code: 403, Reason: Forbidden.
NoneType: None
```

Do you have any idea of where I may be going wrong from what I've described? Have I understood [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587486/django-oauth-separate-resource-and-authorization-server) correctly and created the `RESOURCE_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN` in the correct manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when using the `'RESOURCE_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN'`. So instead I used the `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Go ahead and try the following:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/introspect/',
    'RESOURCE_SERVER_INTROSPECTION_CREDENTIALS':
        (
            client_id,
            client_secret
        ),
}
```

That is how it worked for me.